# POST to SSL'd site from non SSL'd webhook rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl

I have a rails "lead tracking" app that receives POST requests from non SSL'd wordpress sites. When I tell the wordpress form to POST to http://example.com/form_leads it works no problem but when I tell it to POST to https://example.com/form_leads it does not work. Any ideas here? No idea where stuff is being filtered out in the chain.

It's rails 4.2 on a Heroku server with a wildcard SSL setup.

I don't have force_ssl activated.

Is there something that I have to change?

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work"? Can you manually execute the POST via `curl -vv -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"field1":"value1","field2":"value2"}' https://example.com/form_leads`?

Comment: Simply doesn't even show up in my logs or anything. 

I tried to POST to an https ngrok link and it got through to ngrok, but it never got to my rails controller where I had a binding.pry so I could debug.

it's like it was being filtered out somewhere in the request chain but I didn't see it in my logs or anything at all so really not sure?

Comment: I just tried it with HTTParty and it worked with both URL's so now I think it might not be my rails app but where it's posting from?